# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.model.DefaultUploadedFile cannot be cast to java.io.File

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces upload file component  everything works fine : 
my problem that I need to retrieve the uploaded file :

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)  {
   selectedFile=(File) event.getFile();    
  }
```

the uploaded file has DefaultUploadedFile type class but I need File class type . I try to cast it but I get cast error so i found another solution it's creating the file using the DefaultUploadedFile URI

```
selectedFile=new File(Uri)
```

but I couldn't find a way to retrieve it from `event.getFile()`

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't be interested in the `File` of the *temporary* upload file location at all (it will be deleted afterwards!). You should be creating a `File` on a fixed location **yourself** and write the uploaded file's content to it which you can just get by `getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method get `InputStream` from `UploadedFile`. And from `InputStream` it is easy way to have `File`. Example ([How to convert InputStream to File in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/))

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)  {        
    UploadedFile selectedFile = event.getFile();
    InputStream inputStream = selectedFile.getInputstream();    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can cast ist to `java.io.File`. The instance returned by the `getFile()` method is of type `UploadedFile` (which is completely unrelated to java.io.File). You could however use the `getInputStream()` method in order to retrieve an `InputStream` and read the file like so:

```
UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
// do something useful with the input stream...
```

The UploadedFile interface provides other useful methods to inspect the uploaded file. For more information see: http://www.dzeek.net/javadoc/primefacesdocs/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html